# Htaccess clean user profile url is not redirecting

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I cannot get the clean user profile url to work. I already tried everything!
I want to redirect

```
http://localhost/test/profile?username=gadgetster
```

to

```
http://localhost/test/profile/gadgetster
```

Here is my attempt:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

why isn't this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile\.php\?username=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ profile/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure there is no `.htaccess` in `/test/profile/`.

Comment: this is not changing anything in the url, and there is only one .htaccess file in the main test folder where the profile.php is also

Comment: check updated code and also tell what exact URL are you entering in browser?

Comment: I copied that whole code you posted and entered http://localhost/test/profile.php?username=gadgetster and nothing happened

Comment: got it working using the code you gave me on my other question for the post id, same code just changed the post to profile and id to username!